# How to integrate old android styles into titanium alloy

Tags: android, xml, titanium, titanium-alloy

i am converting one of my android apps into titanium alloy, I have some selector xml for buttons which are kept in res/drawable folder(custom_btn_genoa.xml), shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item android:state_pressed="true" >
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="3dip" />
         <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#20534e" />
         <gradient  android:angle="-90"  android:startColor="#062d30" android:endColor="#4c898e"  />            
     </shape>
 </item>
<item android:state_focused="true">
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="3dip" />
         <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#20534e" />
         <solid  android:color="#125156"/>       
     </shape>
 </item>  
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="3dip" />
         <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#20534e" />
         <gradient  android:angle="-90"  android:startColor="#4c898e" android:endColor="#125156" />            
     </shape>
 </item>
</selector>
```

Then my buttons styles (values/styles.xml)

```
<style name="btnStyleGenoa" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
   <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
   <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
   <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
   <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
   <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
   <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
   <item name="android:shadowRadius">0.6</item>
   <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_btn_genoa</item>
   <item name="android:padding">10dip</item>
   </style>
```

In titanium i can set the textsize, color, and so forth, but how can i implement the selector xml stuff in titanium alloy easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion from Android styles to Titanium is not one to one, it is meant to be generally applicable to multiple platforms (iOS, Android, Windows, Blackberry). In this case (if you are trying to emulate a button selector) this is built in to Titanium, here is an approximation of the selector to Alloy xml for what you have:

```
<Alloy>
        <Button id="button" title="Hello" 
                top="10" width="100" height="50" 
                color="#FFF"
                backgroundFocusedColor="#125156" 
                backgroundColor="#125156"  
                backgroundSelectedColor="#4c898e"/>
</Alloy>
```

The backgroundFocused and Selected each specify different images or colors to use when a user interacts with the button.